# Weird pops and cracks in my Reaper input?

Tags: daw, reaper, behringer

I am trying to record some simple guitar into a track on Reaper and I keep getting weird pops and cracks, but not all the time (see bottom).

I recorded a sample of what's going on at the end of this audio clip:

I have tried using both my Shure SM57 and SM58 microphones with no difference. I have also tried switching my xlr cable and switching the USB port from my interface to my computer.

I am using Reaper and an ASIO4All driver who's buffer size I have tried setting to 256 512 and 1024 all to no avail. I have all of this installed on my HP Omen laptop computer which I use for video games, and should have plenty of processing power.

I am recording on a behringer interface I purchased a few days ago from amazon: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00QHURUBE/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00QHURUBE)

I am getting worried that this noise might be coming from my interface but I don't have another interface to try recording from.

Additional info that may have been just coincidence:

This problem has been getting worse all day (I've been at it for almost 7 hours now). It started off as happening every once in a while and I'd restart reaper and it would go back to normal. Then it wouldn't stop unless I recorded on a new track (making a guitar 2 track for recording and then dragging it to guitar 1 once it was done recording). Finally it sounds like that about 50% of the time and I just have to wait a little while for it to stop. In addition to the crappy sound I linked to, all day it has been inserting little cracks and pops into what I record, maybe once every 45 seconds or so.

EDIT 1: I switched my driver from ASIO4ALL to the Behringer specific driver for my interface, as well as increasing the sample rate way up to 2048 and it seems to have resolved the issue for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your buffer size is set too low.

I'm using your audio interface's larger brother and I'm not having any issues with the buffer. It's set at 256 samples @ 96kHz and I get just under 5ms latency glitch-free.

Maybe this is caused by ASIO4all? I don't really know. Have you tried using the Behringer software (driver) to set the buffer size (of course you will have to pick the Behringer asio driver in Reaper instead of ASIO4all)?

If this doesn't fix it, are you by any chance syncing to an external clock? I've had similar sounding glitches when I connected an audio interface to a digital mixer without setting the clock parameters first (master/slave).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried setting it to 256, 512, and 1024 within reaper, but I will try setting it within ASIO4ALL and then try downloading Behringer's software and setting it in there. By syncing to an external clock do you mean a clock outside of my computer?

Comment: It turns out that the buffer size within my ASIO4ALL has been set to 512 the whole time, and what I have been adjusting is the 'block size' within the Audio Device Settings of Reaper. Is there a difference between these two and is 512 still too low?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and what would recommend and what worked for me is make sure the two boxes by the bottom are checked when setting up your driver in reaper! Especially the (Ignore asio reset messages, needed for some buggy drivers) box
[image]